# problem regarding transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, effect

How to put transition on a web page? I have tried,  but it doesn't worked on internet explorer. how to add transition during opening page? transitions effects like fades,dissolves etc. same as in ppt's

Comment: What did you try? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by 'transition'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CSS3 transitions/animations ([CSS3Please.com demo here](http://css3please.com/)), be aware that IE is lacking in support for these almost entirely - it is unclear but unlikely that the new IE9 will have CSS3 transitions.

This is a good article written about CSS3 transitions/animations this week:
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/11/17/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-3-transitions/.

Decide whether transitions are necessary for IE based on the demographics/browser preferences of your user base, and also knowing that IE users are far less likely to expect such transitions (because fewer developers make the effort). Unless it is truly critical that your site looks gorgeous in IE it's usually acceptable to make IE functional, while implementing transitions for the more advanced browsers.

Comment: IE users are a majority, why would they need only a functional version?

Comment: @paulwhit - It's a form of graceful degradation. Where you have a browser like IE7 that has limited support (and slows down a lot) when you introduce rounded corners, gradients, etc, it is perfectly fine to present that user with an optimal experience for that browser rather than insisting on perfectly identical visual experiences. This may mean reducing the number of CSS- or image-heavy components it has to process. The context of my answer doesn't say that IE should be strictly 'functional', but intelligent choices must be made when dealing with older or more limited browsers. A harsh -1.